# Get the results of sp_helptext as a single string

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm running a query using "EXEC sp_helptext Object", but it returns multiple lines with a column name Text.  I'm trying to concatenate that value into a single string but I'm having trouble trying to figure out the best way to do it using T-SQL.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can try something like this

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE(
        Val VARCHAR(MAX)
)

INSERT INTO @Table EXEC sp_helptext 'sp_configure'

DECLARE @Val VARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT  @Val = COALESCE(@Val + ' ' + Val, Val)
FROM    @Table

SELECT @Val
```

This will bring back everything in one line, so you might want to use line breaks instead.

Comment: @gbn answer is cleaner in my opinion, although both do the job.

Answer (score 7):

Assuming SQL Server 2005 and above (which is implied by varchar(max) in astander's answer), why not simply use one of these

```
SELECT OBJECT_DEFINITION('MyObject') 

SELECT definition FROM sys.sql_modules WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID('MyObject')
```

Comment: Using this from SQSH gives me: Unicode data in a Unicode-only collation or ntext data cannot be sent to clients using DB-Library (such as ISQL) or ODBC version 3.7 or earlier.

Answer (score 2):

This is not very glamorous, but it works ...

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE(
        Val VARCHAR(MAX)
)

INSERT INTO @Table EXEC sp_helptext 'sp_configure'

DECLARE @Val VARCHAR(MAX)

SET @Val = ''

SELECT  @Val = @Val + REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(Val, CHAR(10), ''), CHAR(13), ''), CHAR(9), '')
FROM    @Table

-- Replaces line breaks and tab keystrokes.

SELECT @Val
```